# strange behavior json_decode

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I'm creating a json in javascript in that way

```
jsonArr.push({
            position: 'WN',
            wind: windWN,
            wave: waveWN,
            sea:  seaWN
        });
        var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonArr);
```

I'm sending it via an AJAX method with jsonData: `jsonData:Ext.encode(myJsonString)`

My json array looks like that when I send it : 
[image]

In PHP side, I'm getting the Json and decoding it that way :

```
$rawpostdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$rawpostdata2 = json_decode($rawpostdata, true);
```

I tried `print_r( $rawpostdata2[1]);` and got '{', as the second character of the "string", and I can't understand why.

In the other side, I tried `print_r($rawpostdata)`, cut/past the result in a $string and retest my json_decode like that :

```
$rawpostdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
// print_r($rawpostdata);
$string = '[{"position":"N","wind":"2","wave":"65","sea":"65"},{"position":"E","wind":"3","wave":"5","sea":"6"},{"position":"S","wind":"56","wave":"4","sea":"8"},{"position":"W","wind":"1","wave":"56","sea":"84"},{"position":"NE","wind":"5","wave":"6","sea":"65"},{"position":"ES","wind":"6","wave":"45","sea":"6"},{"position":"SW","wind":"69","wave":"8","sea":"4"},{"position":"WN","wind":"7","wave":"8","sea":"56"}]';
$rawpostdata2 = json_decode($string,true); 
print_r ($rawpostdata2[1]);
```

It gives me the correct result !

> Array (
>       [position] => E
>       [wind] => 3
>       [wave] => 5
>       [sea] => 6 )

Do you have some explanations?

**EDIT :** I make it working by making another json_decode

```
$rawpostdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$rawpostdata2 = json_decode($rawpostdata,true); 
$rawpostdata3 = json_decode($rawpostdata2,true);
```

But I don't really understand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you create json string:

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonArr);
```

Then you encode the resulting string into json again:

```
Ext.encode(myJsonString)
```

Thus, you have to `json_decode()` twice in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try using $_POST instead of `file_get_contets()` which gives you a [string](https://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Answer (score 1):

you need to do a type cast on the result of json_decode like this:

```
<?php 
    $rawpostdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $rawpostdata2 = (array) json_decode($rawpostdata,true);
?>
```

I hope this works for you.. Cheers..!!